# How to handle react native firebase admob ads on screen rerender?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, admob, react-native-firebase

I am trying to implement react native firebase ads into my application. I have noticed that whenever a component mounts, render method is called many times leading the ad to rerender multiple times. I think rerendering the ad within 60 seconds is against the google policies. Is there any way I can prevent this rerendering whenever a component mounts.

Answer (score -2):

NO. No Way. its impossible. you just cannot do it

Comment: Can you elaborate on why he cannot do it?